# How do I get two different values from an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Does anyone how I would go about to get two target values from an option using useState in react/nextjs?

My api kinda looks this:

```
const movies = [
   {
     id: 1,
     name: "Fight Club"
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: "Titanic"
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: "The Lion King
   }
]
```

And the code, which doesn't work and is more a wishfull thinking, looks like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
   const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_URL}/Movies`);
   const data = await res.json();

   return {
      props: {
         movies: data
      }
  }
}

function CreateMovieNight({ movies }) {
   const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState("");
   const [selectedMovieId, setSelectedMovieId] = useState("");
   const [selectedSnack, setSelectedSnack] = useState("");

   // In here will be a fetch POST function

   return (
      <div>
         <h3>Pick Movie</h3>
         <select
            name="Movie"
            value={selectedMovie}
            onChange={(event) => {
               setSelectedMovie(event.target.value),
               setSelectedMovieId(event.target.value)
            }
         >
            {movies.map((movies, index) => (
               <option key={index} value={movies.name}>
                  {movies.name}
               </option>
            ))}
         </select>
      </div>
   )
}
Export default CreateMovieNight;
```

Obviously this doesn't work. I understand that both selectedMovie and selectedMovieId will be set with the value from movies.name.

But what I want to do is list all the movies based on names for the user and when the user have chosen one movie selectedMovie gets updated and also the selectedMovieId gets updated with the corresponding id.

I hope that I have made myself understood and I thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store *both* the name *and* the ID.  You can already derive from data the record you want based on a unique identifier, so just store that identifier.  The *id* of the "selected movie".

Use the `id` as the form element value:

```
<option key={index} value={movies.id}>
```

And store the selected `id` in state:

```
onChange={e => setSelectedMovieId(e.target.value)}
```

So `movies` contains all of the records, and `selectedMovieId` contains an identifier for the "currently selected" record.